# Python: os.path.isdir behaving strangely if the directory name has been changed to an equivalent one?

Tags: python, operating-system

I am seeing a very strange behavior coming from these two commands:

```
k = [name for name in os.listdir('/home/kwotsin/Datasets/flowers/') if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

versus the following command when I run it in a terminal on the path above:

```
k = [name for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

When I run this to check:

```
k = [name for name in os.listdir('/home/kwotsin/Datasets/flowers/')]
for name in k:
    print os.path.isdir(name)
```

I get False instead, although `k` actually has a subdirectory listed in it!

The first one returns me nothing while the second one returns me a list of subdirectories. Why would this happen?

Comment: Not sure how you get 'False' as output given that code. Which one is strange: tje list with the absolute path or the list with the relative path?  Showing the output would help explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a problem because `name` (coming from `os.listdir`) will only contain the last part of the path and therefore be a *relative path*. `os.isdir('testdir')` will only look for `'testdir'` in your current working directory (`os.getcwd()` will tell you which one that is; that is also what is referenced by `'.'`).

you could fix that with something like

```
my_dir = '/home/kwotsin/Datasets/flowers/'
...
if os.isdir(os.path.join(my_dir, name)):
    ...
```

because now `os.path.join(my_dir, name)` is the *absolute path* of the directory/file called `name` in `my_dir` and it will be found independently of your working directory.

just in case: [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a nice built-in module for path handling...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That makes sense given that `name` is not attached to any directory. I would understand why Python doesn't give True for os.path.isdir.